# Tab menu not working with AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, tabs, zend-framework2

Got a tab menu from http://www.menucool.com/tabbed-content, This works fine on load of the webpage.
My issue is when I click on a button, AJAX is done and content will be loaded (with this tab menu content), but the its not working as normal.

Here are my screen shots with on page onload and AJAX load,

**Normal Page load**
[image] 
Works fine

**AJAX load**
[image]

Not working

May be the js file will be loaded only for page load.

How can can make it work for AJAX

My AJAX,

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: destinationUrl,
        data: content, // my parameters
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) { // data is tab menu content
        $('#successDiv').html(data); // data is populated in successDiv
        }
    });
```

There are no errors in console. But tabbing is not working with ajax as working in page load

Comment: Could you provide your current code?

Comment: You mean my ajax code??

Comment: kindly post your code

Comment: I have my css file and js file from the above link, I followed just as mentioned in the site and works fine for whole page load. My ajax is also working, but js file is not loaded with ajax

Answer (score 0):

According to the example in: http://www.menucool.com/tabbed-content

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#view1">Features</a></li>
    <li><a href="#view2">How to Use</a></li>
    <li><a href="#view3">Source Code</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tabcontents">
    <div id="view1">
        content 1
    </div>
    <div id="view2">
        content 2
    </div>
    <div id="view3">
        content 3
    </div>
</div>
```

you could do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("ul.tabs li a").click(function(){

        var menuId = $(this).prop('href');
        var el = $(menuId);
        menuId = id.substring(1);

        var request = $.ajax({
          url: "script.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: {id : menuId},
          dataType: "html"
        });

        request.done(function(msg) {
          el.html( msg );
        });

        request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
          alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
        });         

    })

})
```

Comment: The whole tab content is from ajax, so the design will be shown as in screenshot2

Comment: In tabcontent.js I can see EventListener("DOMContentLoaded"), can be due to this??

Comment: It could happen because of various reasons you should provide some of your code and the error log.

Comment: Yes, only js is not working, Sorry did forget to tell that I am using zend framework and for AJAX, the layout will be disabled so that only content will be taken all other including head will be excluded